# More formal way to say "all-nighter"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, nouns

What is a more formal way to say "all-nighter" in a sentence, such as "I pulled my first all-nighter, when writing a report with my group"?

Rewording "my first all-nighter" as "I *stayed awake all night for the first time when* writing a report with my group" sounds quite awkward (and is awfully long). Is there a more formal noun similar to "all-nighter" (which I can modify with the adjective "first")? Or perhaps a better way to reword the sentence?

Comment: I was up all night writing that report.

Answer (score 2):

**Worked through the night.**

> I worked through the night for the first time when writing a report for my group.

Verbs other than "worked" are just as correct; for example "played through the night" or "marched through the night".